# Could having auto focus enabled be causing tracking issues in my AR scene?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore

I am building an AR scene onto a Galaxy S7 using AR Core and Unity 2018.2.20f where I use the AugmentedImageVisualizer to track an image and place a 3d gameObject in front. In order to track the image, I need autofocus enabled. The issue is that my anchor jitters around and sometimes completely moves away and disappears. From debugging it seems to be that the camera autofocus might be causing the tracking issue.

My best workaround so far is to switch the camera config to fixed once the image has been detected, but 1/3 of the time the anchor moves while switching to fixed focus. If the anchor is still in sight once the camera is on fixed focus the tracking works great.

Has anyone else noticed this issue before? Is there a way to control the camera focus more specifically?

Answer (score 0):

If you use ARCore version 1.9 or above, the tracking of the Augmented Images is improved than the previous versions. Please find the official releases from the link below.

**Link:** https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-unity-sdk/releases

Having the config in Auto Mode would be fine, as far as the debugging is concerned. Sometimes, if you are using both plane tracking and Augmented images in the config, the jittering might appear.

Also, there is no need to use an Augmented Visualizer to detect the Augmented Image. The following piece of code could help out to track the Augmented Image and Place any 3D Object.

```
using GoogleARCore;

private List<AugmentedImage> augmentedImages = new List<AugmentedImage>();

public GameObject AndyObject;//object to place on the image

private bool Is_Placed=false;

void Update()
{
  Session.GetTrackables<AugmentedImage>(augmentedImages, 
                          TrackableQueryFilter.Updated);
  foreach (var image in augmentedImages)
  {
    if (image.TrackingState == TrackingState.Tracking &&     Is_Placed==false)
    {
       Anchor anchor=image.CreateAnchor(image.CenterPose);
       var andyref = Instantiate(AndyObject,image.CenterPose.position,
                                     image.CenterPose.rotation);
       andyref.transform.parent=anchor.transform;
       Is_Placed=true;//To only place the object once
     }
   }
}
```